# PL SQL SELECT Case Statements involving aggregate values

Tags: plsql, teradata

I'm trying to write a query that in Teradata but I'm not sure how to do it; my table looks like this:

col1: text (account_number)
col2: text (secondary account number)
col3: text (Primary_cust)

the business requirements are:
"Group records by account number.
If there is only one record for an account then keep that record.
If there are multiple records for an account number then:
(1) if only one record has Primary_CUST = 'Y' then keep.
(2) if multiple records have Primary_CUST = 'Y' then keep one with lowest SCDRY_ACCT_NBR
(3) If no records have Primary_CUST = 'Y' then keep one with lowest SCDRY_ACCT_NBR.

I know I need a CASE statement and I'm able to write the first requirement, but not sure on the second.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to think about how to order the rows to get the row you want on top, seems to be like this:

```
SELECT * FROM tab
QUALIFY
   Row_Number() 
   Over (PARTITION BY account_number   -- for each account
         ORDER BY Primary_CUST DESC    -- 'Y' before 'N' (assuming it's a Y/N column)
                 ,SCDRY_ACCT_NBR       -- lowest number
        ) = 1                          -- return the top row
```

Of course `QUALIFY` is proprietary Teradata syntax, if you need to do this on Oracle you have to wrap it in a Derived Table:

```
SELECT *
FROM
 (
   SELECT t.*,
      Row_Number() 
      Over (PARTITION BY account_number   -- for each account
            ORDER BY Primary_CUST DESC    -- 'Y' before 'N' (assuming it's a Y/N column)
                    ,SCDRY_ACCT_NBR) AS rn-- lowest number
   FROM tab 
 ) AS dt
WHERE rn = 1                              -- return the top row
```

Comment: Awesome!  I didn't even think about partitioning- thank you very much!